# MBP Late 2011 macOS Sierra - First Time Kernel Panic - Looking to see if anyone knows the cause based on the log

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I woke up this morning to find my Macbook pro (running macOS 10.12.6 [16G2136], 13inch, late 2011, 2.8 GHz i7, 8GB of 1067 MHz DDR3 RAM) had rebooted. There was an open Problem Report and the details of which suggest a kernel panic.

Before I went to bed, everything was working fine. Only thing I did before bed was transfer an audiobook to my iPad wirelessly through iTunes.

Here is the problem report log. I hope one of you may be able to decipher what caused this to happen. It has never happened before, so I'm hoping it was just a 1 off. But I would appreciate any insight you may be able to provide.

```
Anonymous UUID:       289B3556-1FF7-C5A2-7577-07B09310F360


Wed Feb 26 09:01:05 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802bbfe255): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fadddaeb9, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff812f790007, CR3: 0x000000002f4d7000, CR4: 0x00000000000626e0
RAX: 0xffffff812f78fffe, RBX: 0x0000000000000069, RCX: 0x000000000000002e, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff91367b3bb0, RBP: 0xffffff91367b3c00, RSI: 0x0000000000000018, RDI: 0xffffff812f78ff00
R8:  0xffffff91367b3b68, R9:  0xffffff812f268800, R10: 0xffffff8040362e68, R11: 0x0000000000000003
R12: 0xffffff803e9a6400, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff812f740f00, R15: 0xffffff804e93a400
RFL: 0x0000000000010212, RIP: 0xffffff7fadddaeb9, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff812f790007, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91367b3840 : 0xffffff802bae837c
0xffffff91367b38c0 : 0xffffff802bbfe255
0xffffff91367b3aa0 : 0xffffff802ba993b3
0xffffff91367b3ac0 : 0xffffff7fadddaeb9
0xffffff91367b3c00 : 0xffffff7fadd9433f
0xffffff91367b3c60 : 0xffffff7fadd65d3d
0xffffff91367b3cc0 : 0xffffff7fadd65e83
0xffffff91367b3d40 : 0xffffff7fadd65f8e
0xffffff91367b3d80 : 0xffffff7faca7418f
0xffffff91367b3dc0 : 0xffffff7faca6f9d4
0xffffff91367b3df0 : 0xffffff802c0be07a
0xffffff91367b3e60 : 0xffffff7faca6fa3b
0xffffff91367b3eb0 : 0xffffff7faca740ff
0xffffff91367b3ee0 : 0xffffff802bd84472
0xffffff91367b3fb0 : 0xffffff802ba98957
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7faca67000->0xffffff7faca93fff
         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331(800.21.30)[13A4F807-15BD-3213-85E0-F4F8586A8BF4]@0xffffff7fadd5e000->0xffffff7fadf4cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D5DA7B81-DCD5-39AC-8DC9-796A4D1D6A20]@0xffffff7fac331000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2)[2083CD35-BAC3-3943-9A87-A43462DB7F2D]@0xffffff7fad42c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7faca67000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16G2136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun  2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9778BC83-2647-3AE4-A7F2-8A2F41FA8791
Kernel slide:     0x000000002b800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802ba00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802b900000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2118123094753955
last loaded kext at 940314425688791: com.nomachine.driver.nxau  4.1.b2 (addr 0xffffff7faecac000, size 36864)
last unloaded kext at 222323432657: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.1 (addr 0xffffff7facc54000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
com.nomachine.driver.nxau   4.1.b2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.0.14
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.14.52b52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   279.48
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.5f7
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.20
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.4
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 252
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  341.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.10
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.21.30
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   174
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.52b52
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   516.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    515.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.52b52
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.5f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.5f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.5f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.5f7
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   266.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.19
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM 87.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3032302E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.30)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f7, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK7559GSXF, 750.16 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Thanks,

hexd

Answer (score 1):

Prime suspects are always 3rd party kexts.

In this instance, NoMachine, as it was the last loaded, a very old version & a beta.

If that's not it, then VirtualBox.

Comment: what to do about them sir? ;p